# Drupal showing data from a python script in background :Asynchronous Solution

Tags: php, python, drupal-modules

I m wrting a drupal  module (of course i followed the tutorial and reading pro drupal development etc) .In the  Back-End (in a server  side manner) a python script, scheduled with crontab, fetchs xml-data from a device (each 1-5minute , not time critical at all) and then ,after parsing it , stores the data in a mysql database. --> no problems here .

In the Front-End these data should be presented thanks to  a drupal module that should be able to fetch and show (to the clients on the net) these infos in graphic charts( with simple tables or in rddtool style)-->problems start here

I don't know how to let drupal present this data and graphics (while the python script fills the database how is possible let drupal automatically draw the graphics or fill a simple table with raw data?
(example:columns= 'probe' 'inputs' 'errors' 'currently monitored data'   ->rows='testprobe' '3' '5' '38mbit/s'.

i know i have to connect to db from drupal but the problem is:

1)the automation (poormanschron ? , a while true loop?)

2)graphs creations with php(which are the most simple apis ?.I can use jpgraph (google api maybe) ,php-->which tool is the easiest and well- documented ?

I don't know which books and docs to study; ok i'm a newbie but i only need keywords and directions. 
thanks for your help

Comment: I'm having a hard enough time just counting how many questions are here, let alone starting to answer the rather vague ones you've included... paragraphs and specific questions are your friends.

Comment: sorry for that .I edited it. I hope it's better this time ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/rrdtool. This module integrates RRDTool with Drupal.
For automation you can use [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_cron/6).

Comment: thank you rik. but this module is capable to load data from the  db populated by python or the script has to create an rrdtool file?